# How to scale pyopengl texture size to pygame window size?

Tags: opengl, pygame, textures, pyopengl, opengl-compat

Windows size : 640 * 480

Texture size : 1280 * 720

Hello, How can I scale the texture to the pygame window?

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not just pictures of it. On many devices and for people with accessibilty issues, your pictures are unreadable. Additionally, if anyone wants to reproduce your problem they would have to retype your code. Please make it easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've setup an orthographic projection:

```py
glOrtho(0, self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight, 0, -1, 1)
```

If you want the texture to fill the whole window, then you have to draw a quad corresponding to the orthographic projection and the texture coordinates form (0, 0) to (1, 1):

```py
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

glBegin(GL_QUAD)

glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
glVertex2f(0, 0)

glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
glVertex2f(self.windowWidth, 0)

glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
glVertex2f(self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)

glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
glVertex2f(0, self.windowHeight)

glEnd()
```

If you wan to keep the aspect ratio of the texture, then you have to scale the size of the quad. For instance:

```py
left = 0
top = 0
width = self.windowWidth
height = self.windowHeight

sx = self.windowWidth / textureWidth 
sy = self.windowHeight / textureHeight 
if sx > sy:
    width *= sy / sx
    left = (self.windowWidth - width) / 2
else:
    height *= sx / sy  
    top = (self.windowHeight - height) / 2

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

glBegin(GL_QUAD)
glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
glVertex2f(left, top)
glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
glVertex2f(left + width, top)
glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
glVertex2f(left + width, top + height)
glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
glVertex2f(left, top + height)
glEnd()
```

Comment: I replaced pygame with glfw. but the video display is static.

Comment: @seeu Sorry, but that is a new question. Pleas [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide the new code. But do use screen shots of the code, you have to past the code to the new question.